# How can I see the claims of my ally?

Tags: stellaris

My federation ally has proposed a war to conquer territory of another empire. Before I accept I would like to know which systems he has claimed, which would be important to know for winning the war. Also I am considering to add some claims of my own.

How can I see the existing claims of my ally on another empire?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a couple of way how you can see the existing claims of your ally.

### Map

You can see the claims of your ally on the map. Switch to "Diplomatic Map Mode" and then click on you ally, so you see his view of the world. His claims will show up as cyan circles around the systems (usually on his border).

This is properly the most efficient way since you can quickly get an overview on which systems your ally has claimed.

[image: Diplomatic view with claims]

### Claim window

In the claim window hover with your mouse of the systems you suspect your ally has claims. You can see in the tooltip if the system is claimed by anyone.

[image: Claim window tooltip]

### System view

Finally you can also see existing claims in the system window. Just hover with your mouse over the "Add claim" symbol and you can see any existing claims of that system in the tooltip.

[image: System window tooltip]